# Find Shortest Path in a directed weighted graph from list of sources and list of destinations

Tags: java, algorithm, shortest-path

First of all is that my Graph contains **negative weights** so I can't use Dijkstra's algorithm.

I tried to use and edit a kind of Floyd-Warshall algorithm, but it's good only in some cases. Maybe I have to use an edited version of Bellman-Ford algorithm, but I'm not able to find a way..

```
<EDIT>
```

I'm not able to find a way to have the correct output, not to find the shortest path because I'm able to do it, but to have a correct output in this input. (see the draw and compare it with the output, you can see that is different. for example:

```
2 -> 5     -4    2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

The distance -4 is incorrect, in the draw is -2, while in the other output with a bit different input as described in the post below, everything is correct.

```
</EDIT>
```

Here is my input *(1)* file:

```
6 9
2 3
0 1 -2
0 2 1
2 1 -3
1 3 2
2 3 3
2 5 1
5 3 1
3 4 1
4 5 -3
```

Where `6` is the number of nodes, `9` is the number of edges, `2` and `3` are respectively the sources and the destinations (`0<=sourceNodes<=2` and `3<=destinationsNodes<=5`) where I have to calculate the shortest path.
So, in this input file my code gives me this output and if we see the draw I made for you, it's wrong.

[image: Graph from input 1]

While the Output is:

```
pairs     dist     path
0 -> 3    -1     0 -> 1 -> 3
0 -> 4     0     0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4
0 -> 5    -3     0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
1 -> 3     1     1 -> 3
1 -> 4     2     1 -> 3 -> 4
1 -> 5    -1     1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
2 -> 3    -2     2 -> 1 -> 3
2 -> 4    -1     2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4
2 -> 5    -4     2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Esercizio3 {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/myFiles/Input2Es3.txt"));
        int totNodi = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("totNodi: "+totNodi);
        int totArchi = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("totArchi: "+totArchi);
        // ingressi
        int nIngressi = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("nIngressi: "+nIngressi);
        int[] ingresso = new int[nIngressi+1];
        for (int i=0; i<=nIngressi; i++) {
            ingresso[i] = i;
            System.out.println("> INGRESSO: "+ingresso[i]);
        }
        // uscite
        int startUscite = scan.nextInt();
        //        int endUscite = totNodi-1;
        int nUscite = totNodi-startUscite;
        System.out.println("nUscite: "+nUscite);
        int[] uscita = new int[nUscite];
        for (int i=startUscite; i<totNodi; i++) {
            int index = i-startUscite;
            uscita[index] = i;
            System.out.println("> USCITA: "+uscita[index]);
        }
        // archi
        int V = totNodi;
        int E = totArchi;
        int[][] weights = new int[totArchi][3];
        for (int i=0; i<totArchi; i++) {
            weights[i][0] = scan.nextInt();
            weights[i][1] = scan.nextInt();
            weights[i][2] = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println(weights[i][0] + " - " + weights[i][1] + " - " + weights[i][2]);
        }

        floydWarshall(weights,totNodi,ingresso,uscita);


    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

static void floydWarshall(int[][] weights, int numVertices, int[] ingresso, int[] uscita) throws IOException {

    double[][] dist = new double[numVertices][numVertices];
    for (double[] row : dist)
        Arrays.fill(row, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);

    for (int[] w : weights)
        dist[w[0]][w[1]] = w[2];

    int[][] next = new int[numVertices][numVertices];
    for (int i = 0; i < next.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < next.length; j++)
            if (i != j)
                next[i][j] = j + 1;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < numVertices; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < numVertices; j++)
                if (dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] < dist[i][j]) {
                    dist[i][j] = dist[i][k] + dist[k][j];
                    next[i][j] = next[i][k];
                }

    printResult(dist, next, ingresso, uscita);
}

static void printResult(double[][] dist, int[][] next, int[] ingresso, int[] uscita) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myoutputfile.txt"));

    double distMin =  Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    int indexI = 0;
    int indexJ = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < next.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < next.length; j++) {
            if ((i != j) && (dist[i][j]!=Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) && (i>=ingresso[0] && i<=ingresso[ingresso.length-1]) && (j>=uscita[0] && j<=uscita[uscita.length-1])) {
                int u = i + 1;
                int v = j + 1;
                String path = format("%d -> %d    %2d     %s", i, j, (int) dist[i][j], i);
                do {
                    u = next[u-1][v-1];
                    path += " -> " + (u-1);
                } while (u != v);
                System.out.println(path);



                if(distMin > dist[i][j]) {
                    distMin = dist[i][j];
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

How can I solve this? because with another input it runs perfectly:

Input *(2)* that runs *(it's similar to the first one but a different weight in the last raw)*:

```
6 9
2 3
0 1 -2
0 2 1
2 1 -3
1 3 2
2 3 3
2 5 1
5 3 1
3 4 1
4 5 1
```

Output perfect:

```
0 -> 3     0     0 -> 1 -> 3
0 -> 4     1     0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4
0 -> 5     2     0 -> 2 -> 5
1 -> 3     2     1 -> 3
1 -> 4     3     1 -> 3 -> 4
1 -> 5     4     1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
2 -> 3    -1     2 -> 1 -> 3
2 -> 4     0     2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4
2 -> 5     1     2 -> 5
```

The only thing I know is that for the first input the output should be `-1`, while for the last input the output should be `2 -> 1 -> 3` which is the path with the shortest distance between a source node and a destination node (and it's correct).

Thank you

Comment: Is it worth to normalize weight before? for example you can just find maximum negative weight first and increase all weights on absolute value of the weight

Comment: The problem is not to find the shortest path, because from the algorithm used (floyd-warshall), we know that I can find it, but the problem is for the first input i posted the output is different from the draw. I need to know why the output, only this case, is different from the draw (that is obviously correct).

Comment: result for length = -1 is correct. path for the weight is '0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 3`. problem with track algorithm which not cover cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly if there is a negative cycle then we can't find a shortest path. It is easy to visualize that. Cause if we repeatedly traverse the negative cycle then the cost will decrease for every traversal. As a result we will find infinitely decreasing value of our path.

Well, to avoid this drawback we use Bellman-Ford's algorithm. Which detects whether a graph contains a negative cycle or not. I am assuming you know Bellman-Ford's and Dijkstra's Algorithm and used to with the term "Relaxation".

Now we will follow an approach known as Johnson's algorithm:

- We will add an extra vertex X and connect it to all the other vertices of the graph and the edges will all be of cost 0.
- Taking the new vertex X as source, we will apply Bellman-Ford's
  algorithm. Which will find the shortest path of all the edges from
  the source in a total of *(n-1)* iterations, where *n* is total number of
  vertices including X.
  We will take an extra iteration, from the same source and it will perform differently in two different cases.

  1. Negative cycle present: Relaxation will be seen again to happen.
     It means there is a negative cycle and we can't have a shortest
     path in the graph as I explained above. So, our program should
     terminate.
  2. Negative cycle not present: No relaxation will take place and we got the shortest path of all vertices from X. We are ready to go!
- We will reweight the edges of the original graph using the shortest path from the Bellman-Ford's algorithm. 
  If *u* and *v* has a edge in main graph with cost *w(u,v)* and shortest paths of *u* and *v* from X are *h(u)* and *h(v)* respectively, then new weight  *nw(u,v)= w(u,v)+h(u)-h(v)*.

Now Dijkstra's algorithm from your selected source should find the shortest path to all vertices on the reweighted graph which is also the shortest path of the original graph.

If you are yet confused please check [Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) at Wikipedia.

Comment: this should be correct, but I'm having trouble with the code, could you give me a little example? Also using a pseudocode if you want

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to minimize the total cost of the route as much as possible (result of -6 is better then -3) or get as close as possible to 0 (-3 is better then -6)?
If you are trying to get close to 0, i think this may actually be an [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) problem, where there is no reasonable algorithm, that will give you 100% correct answer. These kind of problems are usually solved either by some heuristic algorithms, that can get you good enough result or if the network of nodes is not that big, you can do enumeration with selecting the best one (writing this network as a linear [programming problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), there are some solvers available for this in php, java ...).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The result must be as less as possible (-6 is better then -3). But the problem is not the result itself, but if you see the draw and the related output, the output is wrong, because - for example -`2 -> 5    -4     2 -> 1 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5`, the distance `-4` is incorrect, in the draw is `-2`, while in the other output with a bit different input as described in the post, everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an adapted Dijkstra. If you detect a cycle leading to a negative result within that cycle you mark the path as "undefined", since the shortest path is "infinite short".

Comment: But I need the negative result, because in the second input-output, the shortest path distances is `-1` from the path `2 -> 1 -> 3`. 
So Dijkstra is impossible to use, 'cause as you know has got the problem with negative cycle. (thanks for the answer!)

Comment: Ok. At first, detect negative cycles and remember these paths. Then use Dijkstra but add the highest negative value to all weights. And subtract this from your result, of course.